# Additive identity of a semiring and sub semiring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, semiring

We know that the identity of a group and its sub groups are same. But I think in case of semirings, the additive identity of a sub semiring may be distinct from that of the semiring. I see a counter example in this regards. Please suggest me whether i am correct?

**Edited.**

I am thinking of the following counter example.

Set $S$ of all simple undirected graphs is a semiring under graph union (addition) and graph intersection (multiplication). Empty graph (vertex less graph) denoted by $(\emptyset,  \emptyset)$ is the additive identity. Suppose $S'$ is the set of all those subgraphs of a graph $G\in S$ whose vertex set is $V(G)$. Then $S'$ is a sub semiring of  $S$ under the same operations with additive identity $(V(G), \emptyset)$, which we call discrete graph.

Comment: What counterexample do you have in mind?

Comment: @Berci I have edited the question now..

Comment: The additive identity is the same, under the normal way you would define graph union (union of unlabelled graphs).

Comment: @MorganRodgers But in $S$, we get $(\emptyset,  \emptyset)\cup G_i=G_i$ for all $G_i\in S$. While in  $S'$, we get $(V(G),  \emptyset)\cup G_j=G_j$ for all $G_j\in S'$.